# Azure QnA Maker Update Confidence

Tags: azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

Is it possible to change **confidence** of Azure QnA answers pragmatically.

Suppose QnA maker API returns 4 possible answers for a question with confidence

1. Answer 1=> 90%
2. Answer 2=> 85%
3. Answer 3=> 80%
4. Answer 4=> 70%

Now we want to sent the confidence of **Answer 3** to 95%. So that this answer will come on top next time for same question.

How to do it with QnA API, any sample code or reference manual?

**Note:** Adding alternative question is not a solution for our problem. As admin can change the confidence of answers, based on their business logic in future.

Comment: Can you help me understand why you would need to manually adjust the confidence? MS will have to confirm but I do not believe this is possible. The whole idea is that the application calculates these percentages automatically based on the utterances/questions in the database. You can't change the calculation, so you need to change the data (via alternative phrasings).

Comment: @billoverton After creating knowledge base, when we test the QnA service, we find that sometimes the correct answer to our question is Answer 2nd or 3rd not the 1st one - this is purely based on our business needs.

Comment: @billoverton we actually need some kind of ranking system/indicator that allow admin/user to choose/upvote any answer that satisfy his/her requirement.So next time any user can see most accepted answer.

Comment: You may want to use the active learning feature. There is a sample in botbuilder-samples but I haven't used it. Should allow you to have the user rate answers which in turn can modify future predictions. It seems you would be able to use that to have an admin feed similar data, but I don't know enough to suggest a course of action. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot

Comment: @billoverton we achieved our requirement by using Metadata field. we are allowing using to up-vote an answer and then saving total up-vote for each answer in metadata field. Then show user answers in order with most up-voted answer on top. Thanks for your help.